# Saving arrays of Strings in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, save

I need a sugestion for my app. I need to save in app some arrays of Strings. How can I do this? Which is the best way for doing this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLite Database or file in the sdcard to store the strings.It depends on how you need to use them.

Comment: in this arrays I have values 1 or 0 which reprezent if the user have voted a photo or not...so I think it is not necessary for using a SQLite Database

Comment: oh really? Actually you need SQL

Comment: You better describe the scenario.You are trying to save the information.if it is not simple enough you should use sqlite.If your data is straight enough you can use shared preference

Comment: Well...there are 5 categorys with photos which user can vote...If the user vote one photo I have to know this and to save one in an array...That mean that I have one array for each category and each array has a different lengh...

Answer (score 3):

If the string array is a constant thing, then you can define it in the resources

```
<string-array name="my_array">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</string-array>
```

You can grab it from the resources later like this

```
String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If every String in your array is only a 1 or a 0, then you can build one large String of everything and put in a SharedPreference. When you fetch the saved value all you have to do is parse it character by character to get your 1s and 0s again.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two different solutions:

1. Using `SharedPreferences`
2. Using `SQLite` Database

You can pick one depending on how many strings you want to save. `SharedPreferences` is commonly used for storing a small amount of data and making it easy to access it. Databases should be used if you want to store a bigger amount of data.